# Reference Error: Module not defined (lasso select code I found on gitHub)

Tags: javascript, github, leaflet

I originally asked this on GIS Stack Exchange but no one is touching it. Thought maybe this was more of a pure javascript issue than a GIS one.

I am a web mapping nube and am trying to add a function to my webmap that allows a user to lasso features for a selection. To do this, I am using this code I found on gitHub:

https://github.com/ImperialCollegeLondon/leaflet-lassoselect

Here is my code as is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Residential Garbage - Monday</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.0.3/leaflet.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.0.3/leaflet-src.js" crossorigin=""></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="/CO_054/JS/utils.js"></script>
    <script src="/CO_054/JS/index.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    var map;
    function init() {
      map = new L.map('map');
      map.setView([37.396,-122.102],14.57);

         // Add the tiled layer            
        var tiles = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {attribution: "Data copyright OpenStreetMap contributors"});
        tiles.addTo(map);

        var mondayLayer = L.tileLayer.wms('http://recolrr01.norcalwaste.com:8080/geoserver/CO_054/wms', {
          layers: 'CO_054:residential_garbage_monday',
          format: 'image/png',
          transparent: true
        });

        mondayLayer.addTo(map);

        // define event handler function for click events and register it

          function Identify(e)
          {
            // set parameters needed for GetFeatureInfo WMS request
            var sw = map.options.crs.project(map.getBounds().getSouthWest());
            var ne = map.options.crs.project(map.getBounds().getNorthEast());
            var BBOX = sw.x + "," + sw.y + "," + ne.x + "," + ne.y;
            var WIDTH = map.getSize().x;
            var HEIGHT = map.getSize().y;

            var X = Math.trunc(map.layerPointToContainerPoint(e.layerPoint).x);
            var Y = Math.trunc(map.layerPointToContainerPoint(e.layerPoint).y);

            // compose the URL for the request
            var URL = 'http://recolrr01.norcalwaste.com:8080/geoserver/CO_054/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&LAYERS=CO_054:residential_garbage_monday&QUERY_LAYERS=CO_054:residential_garbage_monday&BBOX='+BBOX+'&FEATURE_COUNT=1&HEIGHT='+HEIGHT+'&WIDTH='+WIDTH+'&INFO_FORMAT=application%2Fjson&TILED=false&CRS=EPSG%3A3857&I='+X+'&J='+Y;

            //send GetFeatureInfo as asynchronous HTTP request using jQuery $.ajax

            $.ajax({
               url: URL,
               dataType: "json",
               type: "GET",
               success: function(data)
               {
                 if(data.features.length !== 0) {  // at least one feature returned in response
                   var returnedFeature = data.features[0]; // first feature from response

                   // Set up popup for clicked feature and open it
                   var popup = new L.Popup({
                     maxWidth: 300
                   });

                   $('#address-details').html("<b>" + returnedFeature.properties.Address + "</b><br><b>Customer Name:</b> " + returnedFeature.properties.Customer_N + "<br><b>Customer Route:</b> " + returnedFeature.properties.Exist_Rout + "<br><b>Customer Tons:</b> " + returnedFeature.properties.Demand + "<br><b>Container Size:</b>" + returnedFeature.properties.Z1SIZE + "<br><b>Account Number:</b> " + returnedFeature.properties.Z1SVC_);
                  }
                }
            });
          }

           map.addEventListener('click', Identify);

           const lasso = L.lassoSelect({ activeTooltip }).addTo(map);

            lasso.on('pathchange', () => {
              // get selected path (an array of LatLng positions)
              const path = lasso.getPath();

              // or check if a point is inside the selected path
              if (this.lasso.contains(someMarker.getLatLng())) {
                // ...
              }

            });

            lasso.enable();
}



</script>
   </head>
   <body onload="init()">
     <h1 id="title">Mountain View - Residential Garbage - Monday</h1>
     <div id="map" class="smallmap"></div>
     <div id='address-details'>          </div>
     <div id="summaryLabel">
         <p>Click a service location on the map to get more information.</p>
         <p class="legendRed">02X </p><p class="legendGreen">03X </p><p class="legendBeige">04X </p><p class="legendBlue">05X</p>
     </div>
    </body>
  </html>

<style>
.legendRed {
  color: #ff0000;
}
.legendGreen {
  color: #33a02c;
}
.legendBeige {
  color: #fdbf6f;
}
.legendBlue {
  color: #1f78b4;
}
  #map { 
    border: 1px solid #ff0000; 
    float: left;
  }
  #address-details {
    border: 1px solid #00ff00;
    float: right;
    width: 190px;
    height: 100%;

  }
  #summaryLabel {
    clear: both;
  }
</style>
```

And here is the error in the console:

```
12:15:42.775 ReferenceError: module is not defined 1 utils.js:1:1
    <anonymous> http://recolrr01.norcalwaste.com:8080/CO_054/JS/utils.js:1:1
```

And here is the utils.js code:

```
module.exports.contains = function(path, point) {
  // ray-casting algorithm based on
  // http://www.ecse.rpi.edu/Homepages/wrf/Research/Short_Notes/pnpoly.html
  var x = point.lat, y = point.lng;
  var inside = false;
  for (var i = 0, j = path.length - 1; i < path.length; j = i++) {
      var xi = path[i].lat, yi = path[i].lng;
      var xj = path[j].lat, yj = path[j].lng;
      var intersect = ((yi > y) != (yj > y)) &&
                      (x < (xj - xi) * (y - yi) / (yj - yi) + xi);
      if (intersect) {
        inside = !inside;
      }
  }
  return inside;
};
```

In the README file the instructions are as such:

```
    Install the plug-in:

npm install github:imperialcollegelondon/leaflet-lassoselect

    Import the plug-in

import 'leaflet-lassoselect';
```

However, I am on a thin client with limited access to the server and no way of getting to a cmd prompt.

Is there anything else I can do to make this code work or is there another version I could use that would not require a plugin install?

Comment: It may be obvious, but how about initializing ; `module={}; module.exports={}`
first thing in `utils.js` ?

Comment: @user10089632 That removed the error but I don't think it's causing the right action. I'm trying to figure out if there is some way I'm supposed to reference through the "npm install github:imperialcollegelondon/leaflet-lassoselect" which I can't do.

Comment: Absolutely, I suggest you make a research about `module` usage and to not use my previous sugestion unless it is only an isolated object declaration and use (I.E it does not affect the overall logic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not include the `utils.js` file from the plugin, it does not look to be needed at all.

When you see `module` and `module.exports`, it means the file is expected to be loaded through a CommonJS *module loader*, unless the code first checks for the availability of those variables, in which case it is probably part of a *UMD* wrapper, making it possibly suitable for direct browser consumption (i.e. inclusion through a `<script>` tag).

When a code is available through `npm` and expected to be `import`'ed or `require`'d, you will have a `package.json` file available at the root of the project. In this file, look for the `"main"` key: it will tell you which file is actually loaded when imported. If there is no such key, by default the loader will expect an `index.js` file to be available at the root.

There are further subtleties that you will learn through using node, npm and module loaders or build engines.

Comment: @ ghybs I got rid of the utils.js but am now getting an error on the line declaring const lasso = L.lassoSelect({ activeTooltip}).addTo(map); This is giving ReferenceError: activeTooltip is not defined

Comment: Sounds to me like a totally different issue. Please open a new question. In the new question, explain how you came up with your code.

Answer (score -1):

Move all the `<script>` tags to the bottom of your HTML, just before the closing `<body>` tag.

Comment: @ Ron Royston I'm still getting the module is not defined. Also getting an error here: const lasso = L.lassoSelect({ activeTooltip }).addTo(map); 15:45:29.832 ReferenceError: activeTooltip is not defined 1 ResGarbMonday134.html:85:46
 init http://recolrr01.norcalwaste.com:8080/CO_054/ResGarbMonday134.html:85:46
 onload http://recolrr01.norcalwaste.com:8080/CO_054/ResGarbMonday134.html:1:1

Comment: I know the way google maps does it is that they have a callback fire once the map/mapScripts are loaded. Whether using callbacks or the newer and easier `promise` methods, you've got to handle the asynchronous nature of the stuff loaded before running your script against it.